# PYTHON Работа с файлами и строками

Tags: python, строки

```
Помогите организовать нормальный ввод данных из файла
```

Данные в файле дублируются и считываются не верно
Он по значениям должен считывать строку 30 22\n а присваивать 30 , а для b 22 и переходить на следующую строку

значения в файле:
30 22\n
31 32\n
41 313\n
232 434\n

```
        from math import *
def f1(a,b):
    y = a**(sqrt(log(b,a)))-b**(sqrt(log(a,b)))+tan(a*b+3*pi/2)
    return y
def f2(a,b):
    y = tan(a*b+3/2*pi)
    return y
fi = open("lab1_pb_in.txt", "rt") #читать файл
fo = open("lab1_pb_ou.txt", "wt") #писать в файл
#line = fi.readline() # Пропустить строки
line = fi.readline() # заголовка в файле
# Вывести шапку таблицы в файл
fo.write("+======+=========+========+\n")
fo.write("I  X  I   F1   I   F2   I\n")
fo.write("+======+=========+========+\n")
for line in fi: # для всех строк файла
    if line=="\n":
        continue
    c = line.split() # расщепить
    for a in c :
        a = a.replace('\\n','')
        a = int(a)
        print(a)
    for b in c:
        b = b.replace('\\n', '')
        b = int(b)
        print(b)
# Вывод в файл
        fo.write("I {0: .1f} I {1: .1f} I {2: 5.4f} I".format(a, b, f1(a, b)))
        fo.write("{0: 6.4f} I\n".format(f2(a,b)))
        fo.write("+------+---------+""--------+\n")
fi.close() # закроем файлы
fo.close()
```

Comment: `a,b = map(int, line.strip().split())` - как-то так

Comment: теперь ошибка
    a,b = map(int, line.strip().split())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '67\\n'

Comment: a, b = map(int, line.split())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '22\\n'